# I have a queue with a head and a tail. How do I make tail not a next node in the queue to comin in?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a method that allows adding a message object to the existing queue. It's suppose to add node to the queue. The problem is my head = tail with this code.

```
public class P2PMessageQueue {

private P2PMessage head = null;
private P2PMessage tail = null;

public synchronized void enqueue(P2PMessage oMessage){

    P2PMessage oP2PMessage = new P2PMessage();
    oP2PMessage.next= head;
    head = oMessage;

}
```

Comment: Where do you set the value of tail? According to your code, it should still be null after enqueue

Comment: What you mean? If lets say there will be 3 messages in the queue how would you know which one is tail?

Comment: This looks more like a `LinkedList` than a `Queue`

Comment: If it would be a linked list can I leave tail = null?

Comment: could you please edit your question, finding it hard to understand your question

Comment: @JephrenNaicker Done

Comment: I think what you looking for is a double linked list. Could you post the class of P2PMessage

Answer (score 0):

Due to the missing information of your class not posted, Your code should look something like this.

```
public void addToFront(T item) {
    if(!isEmpty())
    {
        ListNode temp = new ListNode(item, head, null);
        head.setPrev(temp);
        head = temp;
    }
    else{//if the list is empty
        head= new ListNode(item, null,null);
        tail =head;//the tail will be the last node even after adding new nodes
    }
    numOfItem++;//track the num of nodes 
}
```